# (On javaFx) Is it Possible set Controls Fx:id One element of that Control Array in Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

as all ready asked is it Possible?
For Example class controller have

```
@FXML
ImageView ImageViewArrays[];
```

set fx:id of one ImageView in Scene Builder ImageViewArrays[1] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think On this Way:   in controller class:

```
    private ImageView s1;
    @FXML
    private ImageView s2;
    @FXML
    private ImageView s3;
    @FXML
    private ImageView s4;
    @FXML
    private ImageView s5;
```

On Scene Builder set fx:id of each ImageView ,s1...s5 and then and intergrade as array

```
ImageView Pic[]=new ImageView{s1,s2,s3,s4};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any direct support in SceneBuilder 1.1 for arrays of controls.

However if you are dealing with a static array of controls on a form, then as Riporter mentioned it is trivial to generate the array of controls during the FXML load operation by including the statement he presented in the Initialize() method of your controller class.

```
Imageview[] m_pics = new Imageview[] {s1, s2, s3, s4, ...};
```

If you are needing to work with a dynamically generated array of controls, you can still use FXML to generate the base instance from which you can create an ArrayList in the controller class's Initialize() method, eg.:

```
private List<ImageView> m_pics;

@FXML
private ImageView iv1;
```

And then in your Initialize() method:

```
private void Initialize() {

    m_pics = new ArrayList<>();
    m_pics.add(iv1);
    :
    :
}
```

In this way, even though you must mix code with FXML in order to get what you want, by the time your controller class object is fully loaded, it still looks to you (or another programmer) like you created an array list of ImageView controls in FXML.